# iPhone SDK: Know when tab on Tab Bar is clicked?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabview

I have a tab bar which displays different views when clicked. When you click a tab for the first time, it calls the viewDidLoad method.  But, it only calls that the first time.

Is there a method that is called when a user clicks back to that tab, since the viewDidLoad won't be called that second time?

(I need to do this to update a UITableView when the user clicks back to a tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course!

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)aTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Your best option when looking for these sorts of things is to look in the documentation, specifically at the delegate for the object you're interested in.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` in UIViewController ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:))

Comment: It's better to use the UITabBarController delegate methods. If the tab contains a UINavigationController the viewWillAppear might be undesirable because it will also be called when controllers are popped of the navigation controller